# C++ problems involving getline() and a loop

Tags: c++

I am working an a school assignment and am beating my head against a wall right now trying to figure out why my program is not behaving as I'd like it to!

```
int main(){
    string input;
    char choice;

    bool getChoice(char);
    string getInput();

    CharConverter newInput; 

    do{
        cout << "Please enter a sentence.\n";
        getline(cin, input);

        cout << newInput.properWords(input) << endl;

        cout << newInput.uppercase(input) << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to do that again?\n";
        cin >> choice;



    } while (getChoice(choice) == true);

    return 0;
}
```

This program works fine on the first round, but I am having a problem when getChoice() == true, and the do while block is looped a second time. On the second loop, the program asks for me to enter a sentence again, but then just jumps to "Would you like to do that again?" without allowing user input or outputting the results of the properWords() and uppercase() functions. I suspect that there is something about getline that I do not understand, but I have yet to find it through my googling. Any help out there?

edit: there was a mistake in my original explanation.

Comment: What input are you using? If there is more than one line in your input stream, getline() will grab the next line without waiting for more input.

Comment: Basically, what I am trying to do is allow the user to enter a full sentence which is passed to the two member functions. I want the user to be able to type a new sentence on the next iteration...and so on.

Comment: I like this question because string vs. char input is one of the things that trips up a lot of people when they first start coding in C/C++ (or many other languages for that matter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because reading input with `getline` does not mix well with reading input character-by-character. When you enter the `Y`/`N` character to indicate if you want to proceed or not, you also press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This puts `\n` in the input buffer, but `>>` does not take it from there. When you call `getline`, the `\n` is right there, so the function returns an empty string right away.

To fix this, make `choice` a `std::string`, use `getline` to read it, and send the first character to `getChoice` function, like this:

```
string choice;
...
do {
    ...
    do {
        getline(cin, choice);
    } while (choice.size() == 0);
} while (getChoice(choice[0]));
```

Comment: That's great! You just made my day.